# Xcode Document Item Settings

Tags: c++, xcode, navigation

When in Xcode you can open the Document Item menu with ^6 (control 6). This menu should show all method declarations/instantiations in the currently displayed file. I use it a lot in our current project, but it seems that not all methods will be displayed in the menu. For instance, if a method declaration looks like:

`virtual void print (std::ostream& os) const;`

The method will not display in the menu, but

`virtual void print (std::ostream& os);`

will show up. It appears that anything after the method's parentheses will cause the method to not appear in the menu (I've seen the same problem with 'override'). Any ideas about how to change this setting in Xcode?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Currently 5.1.1, but I have seen the same issue in 7.2.1

Comment: Hmm. I'm using 7.3.1. And I use C++ daily. What I've noticed is the following. In the .cpp, it properly shows the method with a keyword after the parens, regardless if it is a virtual or not. In the .h, however it has a different behavior. It will show the method provided the trailing keyword is not `override`. `final` or `const` do show up.

Comment: Weird. I see the discrepancy in both the header and .cpp. Do you think it's just a formatting thing? Like different spacing(s) cause different behaviors?

Comment: Not sure. I copied and pasted your code into my header and it showed up fine. Formatting-wise, I just had one leading tab. The rest was as you had typed it in. I do not believe it looks up the hierarchy for correctness of whether or not the virtual exists in the superclass. I also found out that a pure virtual decl will not show up. So you can chalk up `override` and `=0` as the ones that don't appear. I'm not sure how to alter Xcode on these rules, I think it is built in. Sorry, I know this doesn't answer your q.

Comment: It's ok. Kinda a long shot hoping for an answer anyways :)